# Good idea to arbitrage this frame?

Tags: frames

I came across a FB marketplace listing where the seller is having a quick sale of an alleged carbon fiber Opus Andante frame due to a move. He supposedly live in a wealthy area of town, originally bought the frame for a bike build project that he never managed to make time for. While I am currently looking for a frame to do a frame swap, this particular frame wouldn't fit what I'm looking for.

That being said, given the price the seller is offering, I was considering to buy it and the resell it at a different price. I'm aware that these information can be all fake and that the bike could be a stolen/defective good. Hence I'm asking the question here to get some feedback.

Comment: Be careful, a used carbon frame might not be worth as much as you think.

Comment: @mattnz: B/c the epoxy may have worn off by now?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrage   specifically "the practice of taking advantage of a difference in prices in two or more markets"        yeah I had to look it up    +1 for making me google a word.

Comment: This use of arbitrage is not correct, see the explanation on the same wikipedia page "Arbitrage is not simply the act of buying a product in one market and selling it in another for a higher price at some later time. The transactions must occur simultaneously to avoid exposure to market risk".

Answer (score 5):

You can ask for the serial number and see how the seller reacts. If the bike is stolen, the seller would probably not risk telling it to you. If you get no reply after that, you have your answer.

As for fake frames, you could ask for clean pictures of strategic spots that you could compare with pictures of a genuine frame. Sometime the font will be slightly different and the lettering will feel low in quality. You can also compare the finish.

If the seller is trying to tell you a story as to why the price is that low, this may be another red flag. You do not usually need to justify yourself when you sell something.

Finally, if the offer seems too good to be true, as almost always, it probably is!

Comment: I got the serial number from the original receipt, and did a search and found nothing on the serial number. Where are the strategic spots you would ask the seller to send over if they don't exist already?

Comment: @stanigator you mean the seller has shown you the original receipt? As for strategic spots, that would be any details that you notice on a genuine frame that you can compare (lettering, graphics, bar code style, stickers, serial number style/font, logo, how the inside of the headtube and bottom bracket look like, color shade, etc).

Comment: Re: the receipt, as far as I can tell. I have trouble finding the product listing of the same bike though.

Comment: I did some more digging. Apparently the carbon bike model is from 2011. Looks like a legit bike frame but the manufacturing year may create some uncertainty to its durability even though it supposedly wasn't used since 2013.

Comment: @stanigator the year of the frame may be the answer to the low price then and if you also have the original receipt, this starts to look legit. Make sure you carefully inspect the frame if you go pick it up!

Comment: Given I likely won't be able to sell it for much, probably won't make much sense for my efforts then.

Comment: "You do not usually need to justify yourself when you sell something." - well you might if all your potential buyers are suspicious

Answer (score 3):

@olliebulle already mentioned most of the right points. The answer that determined the answer was the year the frame was made. Given the carbon fiber frame was made in 2011 (as @mattnz alluded to), the epoxy may have been worn off already, hence factoring into its value. Given I can't mount disc brakes on it, I decided to pass on it and remain patient for a different frame.